# How to expand a text-containing div while keeping the text immobile

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to create an effect for the logo on my website, basically I wish to have a div appear as a dot that first expands to be a horizontal line, which is easily done by animating the width of a zero-height div.

Then, I wish to have the div's height increase relative to a bisecting horizontal axis (top and bottom move away from each other rather than just the bottom dropping down).  This is also not too hard to accomplish simply by placing the div within a containing div and animating its padding at the same speed the contained div expands.

My problem is with the text within the inner div.  When the div expands, I would like it to appear that the text is being revealed from its horizontal center out.  Like pulling back a stage curtain, but the curtain is horizontal rather than vertical.  However, currently, the text moves with the inner div, making it more appear to be pulled into view from below rather than be sitting stationary and be revealed by the receding inner div.

Here is a minimal functioning example:

```css
@keyframes inner {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 2em;
  }
}

@keyframes outer {
  from {
    padding: 1em 0;
  }
  to {
    padding: 0;
  }
}

.inner {
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: inner 3s;
  height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.outer {
  animation: outer 3s;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <p class="text">TEXT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the nested `.text` element from *the normal document flow* by displaying it `absolute` and position it accordingly, relative to its containing parent element (`.inner`).

With `.text` now removed from the document flow and its position explicitly defined, it will not be subject to proportional changes (like `height`) of its containing element.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
@keyframes inner {
  from {
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    height: 2em;
  }
}

@keyframes outer {
  from {
    padding: 1em 0;
  }
  to {
    padding: 0;
  }
}

.inner {
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: inner 3s;
  height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative; /* required for nested absoulte element */
}

.outer {
  animation: outer 3s;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 20px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <p class="text">TEXT</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I thought of using `position: absolute;` before, but forgot about needing the container to be relatively positioned.  Also, I apologize for the improper markup you had to edit in my post; I'm still getting acclimated to the nuances of SO.

Comment: @steelstring94 No problem, just keep doing your best! Happy I could help, moving forward it's going to be easier for you to remember to declare `relative` positioning on containing elements.

Comment: I noticed this solution breaks when the user changes the browser font size.  The text within the two divs appears too low, for instance, if the font size is increased.  I can reposition it of course, but then it is wrong when the font size is restored to normal.  Is there a way to keep the text centered despite increasing or decreasing font size?

Comment: Accomplished this by setting `line-height` on parent div to 10px less than the height of the div.